# Access ListBoxItem-Controls from code-behind

Tags: silverlight, listbox

in my Silverlight 4 application I have a listbox for which I created an itemtemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource BrushCharacteristicListBoxItemBackground}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockCharacteristicName" Text="{Binding Name}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Margin="6,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockSeperator" Text="=" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Border Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2,2,6,2" Background="{Binding FunctionState, Converter={StaticResource ConvertCharacteristicFunctionState2Color}}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockCharacteristicValue" Text="{Binding CalculatedValue, Converter={StaticResource ConvertDouble2Display}}" Padding="2,0" Foreground="{StaticResource BrushCharacteristicListBoxItemBackground}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ValueOrFunc}" MaxWidth="72"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now I want to access the Controls defined in the template (i.e. TextBlockCharacteristicName) from the code behind. I need this to manually adapt the size of the Controls, which can't be done in an other way.

I hooked into the LayoutUpdated event, but did not found a way to access the controls.
I have tried it with

```
((StackPanel)ListBoxCharacteristics.GetItemsHost()).Children
```

which gives me a the list of the ListBoxItems, but there seems to be no way to get the controls from there. Can anyway help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Are you sure you cannot bind the height of a single item to an (attached) property ? Should be possible.

Comment: I need to adapt the width of a single item, and the problem is, that this width depends on the other ListItems: DesiredWidth = Min(Max(AllSimilarItems), MaxWidth). I don't think that this will be possible with binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the small `VisualTreeEnumeration` chunk of code from this blog:  [Visual Tree Enumeration](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx).

Now you can find your "TextBlockCharacteristicName" elements with this code:-

```
foreach (var textBlock in ListBoxCharacteristics.Descendents()
    .OfType<TextBlock>()
    .Where(t => t.Name == "TextBlockCharacteristicName") )
{
    // Do stuff with each Text block.
}
```